# Weird problem - Glassfish 3.1.1 Server and Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, plugins, glassfish

I have installed Glassfish 3.1.1. Open Source Ed. Server for my development purpose and Eclipse Indigo as my IDE. The add-on(s) i have installed in eclipse are Glassfish Server Tools and Spring 3 Tools from elipse market place. Now the problem i am facing is like when i try to start the glassfish from elipse i got **credential error**. But if i test the server from browser like http://localhost:8080/ it works fine. But funny thing is that when i unplug my pc from internet and try to start the GF server from eclipse it works fine!!! i could not figure out what's happening.

My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise Ed and JDK is 1.7.0

Things i tried to solve the problem

1. Shut down MS SQL Reporting Server(2008)
2. Disable Firewall
3. Turn off Anti-virus
4. Netstat -noa | findstr 0.0.8080 to find process and kill it
5. Stop IIS sever

Comment: Did you see this possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939570/glassfish-3-1-credential-error-in-eclipse

Comment: "credential error" tells us squat. But if it helps, Glassfish integration with Eclipse works best when you leave the administrator password blank, when you create the domain, and configure the plugin to use the domain.

Comment: Hm, also the part of leaving the admin password blank? The `CREDENTIAL_ERROR` indicates a wrong password. See also the comment of @Vineet.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved the problem. It was due to the proxy setting. I added "127.0.0.1 localhost"(without quote) in /etc/hosts file and connected my pc to internet, then tried to start the GF server from eclipse . BANG ... it worked !!! (although i did it from my home, i will update this post after testing from my office network).

BTW: @vineet, i tried that too but didn't work. i forgot to mention in the first place. thanks.

Comment: In my case, Preferences, General, Network Connections, Active Provider: Direct solved it too. For what I've read the default "Native" option yields problems as GlashFish by default binds to 0:0:0:0, which causes host name resolution rather than simply "localhost" in things like `JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://my-work-pc.lan:8686/jndi/rmi://my-work-pc.lan:8686/jmxrmi`