# The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server, status is :CREDENTIAL_ERROR

Tags: glassfish-3

I am able to start Glassfish through command line. However, when I try to start the server through Eclipse I encounter  the following error:

> The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server, status is :CREDENTIAL_ERROR

I have checked my login credentials (`admin`/`adminadmin`) and they are correct (I'm able to login into the admin console on port 4848 with the same user/pass). Here is my system info:

- OS: OS X 10.6.7
- Eclipse: Indigo Service Release 1
- Glassfish V3.0.1
- Glassfish Plugin: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6)
- GlassFish user/pass: admin/adminadmin

Please let me know if there is a solution to the problem.

Comment: have you tried without any login/password?

Comment: Yes. Through the admin console I have created a user/password : admin/adminadmin . And still unable to run the server via eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Glassfish 3.1 CREDENTIAL_ERROR in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939570/glassfish-3-1-credential-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: I will suggest checking if your server is running and so it is blocking the default port. If you haven't change it it should be 8080 so check if localhost:8080 responds. If yes then try to kill the server's process and try again. :)

Comment: I just Killed the java.exe processes and it worked straight away!

Comment: how to kill server's process?

Answer (score 14):

Here is what worked for me - after some googling I saw a post saying the error message is misleading and it might be a port conflict. In my Eclipse I have a proxy server entry which uses port 8080 (same as GF). So I changed port to 9090 in domain.xml and GF started no problem. My system is Win7x64, Eclipse 3.7.1, GF 3.1.1

Comment: worked for me , i had tomcat running on port 8080 after a restart.

Answer (score 12):

In the "Servers" view, right-click on the glassfish server and choose "Open"

Within the section "Application Server", ensure that "Use Anonymous Connection for Administrator Commands" is NOT checked off.

---

Application Server

You can edit some runtime properties fro the Application Server(GlassFish or Sun)

Domain Directory

Admin Name

Admin Password

Admin Server Port Number

### _ Use Anonumous Connection for admin Commands.

^

---

If checked, eclipse plugin does not use your login credentials (admin/adminadmin) .

Answer (score 11):

kill java process from task manager if it not show java process then restart your pc >> it work for me

Comment: Thanks ! worked for me .. even after I restarted Eclips I still couldn't start GlassFish but when I killed the java process it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As has been stated a few times here, the port conflict will cause this.  I found that I could not edit the port information in Eclipse, I had to edit the domain.xml file.  I searched for 8080, which took me straight to the  tag.  In here, i changed http-listener-1 form 8080 to 8000.

I then had to remove the GlassFish Server from the Servers tab in eclipse, and re-add it back. (this was many times faster than restarting Eclipse).  now the new port is identified, and I was able to start GlassFish server.

Note: I am using the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, not the generic eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i did "ps -ef | grep java" and realized there was a glassfish process already running. I think it started as part of the installation. I killed it and started the server from Eclipse again and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

There is another service at 8080 (or your port definition in GF settings).
For me, stop this service and try start GF by Eclipse.
Check for Tomcat running, or others apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Anti-Virus Web Scanning settings. Mine had an entry for port 8080 to be scanned for http traffic. I removed it and the server could then be launched without a problem from within Eclipse.

Regards 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is caused to me from AVG Network Scanner Service.
This service is occupying port 8080 !

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem. Fixed by changing permissions of the domain folder to be writable.