# CREDENTIAL_ERROR when starting Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to Start Glassfish inside Eclipse when suddenly this message appear:

> The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with Glassfish server, status
>   is: CREDENTIAL_ERROR

I have tried the solutions given here: Turn off firewall, turn off windows firewall, re-installing glassfish, delete andd again glassfish in Eclipse.

I have Windows 7, but in another computer I have it too and I have worked happy. Then I decided to move project to my notebook, installing all stuff, and this happens.

Any recommendation?

---

### EDITED: SOLVED

**SOLUTION:**
Change Glassfish enviroment from "jre" to JDK 6 or higher. Any doubt, comment here.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6939570/1285418) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7794810/1285418)

Comment: both guys were running Indigo. I am running Helios.

Answer (score 2):

Check it might happen that port configured for the glass fish already in used by other process.

To change prot you can change domain/config/domain.xml

```
    <network-listeners>
      <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
      <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
      <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    </network-listeners>
```

change http port and restart server.

Comment: NOTE: after change the XML file, you might need to delete the glassfish server from your eclipse work space, then re-add again. eclipse seems not able to refresh the new port number