# eclipse cannot connect to glassfish2.1 server

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I have installed eclipse and the glassfish server version 2.1 because this is what the teacher who is teaching the course I am taking gave us instructions for. when I try to connect to the server through eclipse I get an error that says:

"the eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the glassfish server"

the server seems to start just fine and when I browse to localhost:8080 I get a page that says the server is now running. also I can log in when I browse to localhost:4848 with the admin name and password I created. I have searched around and seen people suggest to kill the java.exe process and then retry but this didn't work for me. as far as I can tell there is nothing else running on port 8080. I've tried the suggestions from the other posts but nothing seems to work. any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: I think there was a similar post already:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794810/the-eclipse-plugin-cannot-communicate-with-the-glassfish-server-status-is-cred

Comment: That is the post that I read before. I tried all of the suggestions from there. Tried killing the process and restarting, tried checking if antivirus was blocking ports, checked that no other programs were running on those ports. none of that worked. alos, the other post mentions that it said: "CREDENTIAL_ERROR"    mine does not say this.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download Java EE from:
http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32.zip

Step 2: Download glassfish from :
https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Step 3: Go to Eclipse, open Preferences and add the JDK [image]

Step 4: Go to your project explorer, and open other from new[image]

Step 5: you can find glassfish in servers, if not, from the link Download additional adapters, search for glassfish and you can find it install and it will do an auto restart of eclipse, then you can find glassfish in your server.[image]

Step 6: Do next, next and finish, then you can see the server running in the bottom in servers tab.

Step 7: Open a new project with the type dynamic project and run it. It should work something like this:
[image]

Try this, good luck.