# my eclipse + apache tomcat/6.0.30 stopped serving files

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, tomcat6

I am using the built in tomcat server in eclipse for my debugging and for some reason it stopped working.

I don't know how to start debugging this.

The apache is running (when I go to my servers address (on local host) port 8080 I get an error that is clearly from the apachie server (its a 404).

but it just behaves as if I did not compile anything ...

any ideas on what I should to to step by step debug this situation?

I guess this is because

`C:\Users\myuser\Workspaces\projectName\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\projectName`

is empty.

however `C:\Users\myuser\Workspaces\projectName\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`

does seem to hold a complied version of my web app.

when I right click the server icon on the servers pane and go to properties - general,
there is a "location" value and a change location button.
clicking the button switches the location back and forth between `[workspace metadata]` and `"/Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost.server"` - what doesthose two mean and which is the right one for me?

when I choose build all (after clearing "build automatically" nothing shows up on the console.

another thing I just noticed is that when starting the server I get the following warning:
`WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:projectName' did not find a matching property.`

UPDATE:
after removing the project from the server (right click on project in the servers pane),
it started working again.

but one or two builds after it I got the following message:
`Publishing failed with multiple errors
Could not delete C:/Users/epeleg/Workspaces/projectName/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/projectName/WEB-INF/lib. May be locked by another process.
Could not delete C:/Users/epeleg/Workspaces/projectName/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/projectName/WEB-INF. May be locked by another process.`

and it went back into the same situation with 404's on any request.
remove and re-add of the project did the trick again but I wander why could this be happening.

Comment: Did you try a Clean? Also once you switch locations try & restart Eclipse. From the 404 its evident that its still looking at your empty folder.

Comment: try to see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934922/eclipse-tomcat-deploy-doesnt-work-any-more-classnotfoundexception

Comment: I did try a Clean more then once, and also restarted eclipse more then once. do the two locations I mentioned match the two options switchabe with the "change location" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- delete the server,
- while adding new server - click on "configure runtime environments"
- edit the server specification:

  - point to the location of the server on the disk.
  - JRE to point to the Installed JRE (not to the Workbench default JRE).
- Finish, OK, Finish.
- Untick in menu : Project -> Build Automatically (this should not be selected)
- Right click on project and build it, then run on server.

This should do.

Comment: I thought I would try this, but decided to first just remove the project from the server. when removed and added back, it just started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things listed above, but without success.
Finally, it worked after:
- In my case it was old error regarding deploying project to server, which didn't want to disappear after rebuilding, just remove it from "problem view".
- remove content of target folder in you eclipse project 
-lets process all  "rebuild steps" as cleaning and refresh, rebuild eclipse project, remove your project from Tomcat in Server view and add it again, right click and publish it.