# Issue running a spring 3 app on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, server-configuration, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite with as server VMware vFabric tc Server Developer but I have to change for tomcat6.

There isn't any errors or exceptions when I launch the app but I can't access it because of a 404 error from tomcat.

Here are the logs

```
23 avr. 2013 10:13:12 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\javatools\java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;D:\javatools\java\jdk1.6.0_12;D:\javatools\apache-maven-2.0.10\bin;D:\javatools\java\jdk1.6.0_12;D:\strawberry\c\bin;D:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;D:\strawberry\perl\bin
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ATTENTION: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:dashboard' did not find a matching property.
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initialisation de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-8080
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 599 ms
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Utilisateurs\a553416\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\dashboard\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-8080
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/18  config=null
23 avr. 2013 10:13:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 604 ms
```

Someone would know what's wrong with tomcat or the config ?

Thank you

Comment: The Application seams not to deployed.

Comment: yes I don't know why. There is no errors with the other server

Comment: Try what is suggested in the accepted answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934922/eclipse-tomcat-deploy-doesnt-work-any-more-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

The context path for your application has been changed. Follow this link

[How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Set the context path to URI which is the entry point of your application or which is working in VMware vFabric tc Server.
Undeploy the application from Tomcat and deploy it again.