# Tomcat inside of eclipse doesnt take into account my modifications

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm using a Eclipse and have embedded `Tomcat`. My issue is that sometimes when I edit my servlet, even when restarting tomcat inside of eclipse, the deployed project doesn't update, and  seems to me that it's using a cached version of the files compiled.

How do I do efficiently to make eclipse & tomcat take my modifications into consideration? What folder do I need to clean?

Comment: In the menu - goto projects then clean. Then refresh your project once and retry.

Comment: That has solved my issue but I have a second issue: how do I automatically reload `context`? I have added a `reloadable="true"` to the `<context>` tag, but it doesnt seem to have resolved this problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6084371/1065197. I do the steps from 1 to 3, IMO the other steps are too extreme do do every time I do a simple change :)

Comment: I guess that it would be better to define `ant`/`maven` tasks for those three steps?

Comment: That depends on how you want to optimize the execution of the tasks :).

Comment: If I need everytime to `clean` & `rebuild` my project, then what's the purpose of the `reload context`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution that doesnt need me to `clean` project each time. With it the `context is reloaded` whenever I modify my `servlet`.

In `eclipse`, Goto `Project` and activate the checkbox `Build Automatically`.