# Unable to run my servlet with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm no more able to run a servlet under Eclipse. It worked, but after I deleted the project from the server (Servers view, Tomcat 6) when I right click on the class in the Package Explorer, Eclipse says

> The selection didn't contain any resources that can run on a server

I'm not able to add the project to the server, as it isn't listed in the available servers that can be added.
I tried the procedure listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934922/eclipse-tomcat-deploy-doesnt-work-any-more-classnotfoundexception) but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

**Update**: the project had (partially) lost its nature, i.e. no project facet was selected. However, fixing this wasn't enough, so I created a new Dynamic web project and adapted the .project file and .settings dir. This solved the problem.

Comment: Does Ecplise produce a `.war` file in a `build` directory?