# Tomcat 8.5 in Eclipse 4.7.0 not seeing changed HTML files

Tags: java, html, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Tomcat in Eclipse is ignoring source HTML changes and not publishing them, even though it worked fine before.

I have Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, with Tomcat 8.5.6 installed in `C:\bin\tomcat`. I am running Eclipse Java EE 4.7.0, installed in `D:\bin\eclipse` (a separate volume). Tomcat has been added as an 8.5 server. My workspace is in `D:\workspace` . I have a Maven web application in `D:\workspace\project`, with HTML file `index.html` in `src/main/webapp`. My project has the "Dynamic Web Module 3.1" facet enabled. I have added a "Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost" in the "Servers" tab, and I have added my project to the server. I have turned off caching in my browser.

With the above configuration, on the machine `laptop1` I would start the server and I could access my `index.html` in a browser via `localhost`. If I edited `index.html`, as soon as I saved it Tomcat would quickly show that the files needed publishing, and then would auto-publish the changed file. I could refresh the browser and see the changed HTML file immediately. I worked in this development environment for six to nine months.

I configured a virtually identical machine `laptop2` by installing the same version of Tomcat in `C:\bin\tomcat` as before. I connected the volume `D:` to `laptop2`. I built the project and started Tomcat. I was able to open the browser and see `index.html` via `localhost`.

But now if I edit `index.html`, even inside Eclipse, the changes do not show up in the browser.

- I have used F5 to refresh the project tree.
- I have verified that `src/main/webapp/index.html` has new content and has its timestamp updated.
- The content and timestamp of the files in `target/m2e-wtp/web-resources` do not change after editing `index.html`, even if I restart the server.
- I have removed and re-added the web app from the server in Eclipse, with no change in behavior.
- I have removed and re-added the "Tomcat v8.5 Server" from the "Server" tab, with no change in behavior.
- I have removed and re-added the "Apache Tomcat v8.5" runtime environment from Eclipse, with no change in behavior.
- I have completely disabled Windows Defender using the group policy editor for both `laptop1` and `laptop2`.

I am at a loss to think of what else I could check. I do not know if moving from one system to the other had anything to do with Tomcat stopping recognizing and publishing file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow "Build Automatically" had been disabled.

Yes, the source of all these problems is that somehow in Eclipse the option **Project > Build Automatically** had been turned off. I don't know how. I don't know when. But once re-enabled, everything started working again exactly as it had been before.

I probably would have found this sooner or (much) later, but I stumbled across an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084371/421049) in which @mico mentioned this in passing. I am grateful.